# LinkedIn Share Data URL without Callback Response for Success or Error

Tags: swift, linkedin-api

I know there are so many answer related to share things over LinkedIn, but I do not get any exact scenario that how to share the data over LinkedIn. I use https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares API for share, but there is no callback response for successes even error also. And the main thing is there is no dialog open for share.

Here is my code:

```
var Shareurl : String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"
var payload : String = "{\"comment\":\"Check out developer.linkedin.com!\",\"content\":{\"Heloo Folks\":\"LinkedIn Developers Resources\",\"description\":\"Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement\",\"submitted-url\":\"https://developer.linkedin.com\",\"submitted-image-url\":\"https://brand.linkedin.com/etc/designs/linkedin/katy/global/clientlibs/img/default-share.png\"},\"visibility\":{ \"code\":\"anyone\" }}"

if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession()
    {
        // appInstance.showLoader()

        LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(Shareurl, stringBody: payload, success: { (response) in

            // appInstance.hideLoader()

            let data  = response?.data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            do
            {
                let dictResponse : [String : AnyObject] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                print("LINKED SHARE \(dictResponse)")

                if pbSocialDelegate != nil
                {
                    pbSocialDelegate?.getLinkedinResponse!(userData: dictResponse)
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                print("error")
            }


        }, error: { (error) in
            //appInstance.hideLoader()
            print(error as Any)
        })
    }
```

Please help me that how to open share dialog of Linkedin, and the above code does not through any response or error.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn does not provide any dialog, so if needed, then design your custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to share things over LinkedIn, do you really need the API for this?  Check out the [Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin).  You should be able to share your URL or have others share some URL by setting the `url` param as indicated here:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```